# How to connect array of vectors to dataframe in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, k-means

I have:

```
clustercenters=model.clusterCenters
```

from a kmeans model in `org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans`
The result is `Array[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]`
I want to convert this in a dataframe like this:

```
-------------------------------
|index|Centroid1|...|Centroid6|
-------------------------------
|0    |1        |...|5        |
-------------------------------
```

Any help? Code in scala please